# cannot deploy Rails 4.1.0 application to Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I just tried to deploy my Rails 4.1.0 app to Heroku, but I get this error:

```
Gem::LoadError: Specified 'sqlite3' for database adapter, but the gem is not loaded.

...

error: failed to push some refs to 'git@heroku.com:somedomain.git'
```

For the moment I don't use any database in production.
In my Gemfile, I made the sqlite3 gem only work for development mode like this:

```
gem 'sqlite3', group: :development
```

But this doesn't solve the issue.

Does anybody know how I can deploy my Rails 4.1.0 app to Heroku without specifying a database for production?

Thanks for your help,

Anthony

Comment: add config/database.yml to ur quiestion plz

Answer (score 0):

Its better to use pg gem for heroku.

Your config/database.yml should look this way

```
production:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: appname_production
  pool: 5
  username: user
  password:
```

Gemfile
`gem 'pg`'

This works for heroku in a some of my apps.

Comment: I configured the database.yml file for postgresql in production and added gem 'pg' to my Gemfile, but when I do bundle install, I get this error message:

Comment: No pg_config... trying anyway. If building fails, please try again with
 --with-pg-config=/path/to/pg_config
checking for libpq-fe.h... no
Can't find the 'libpq-fe.h header
*** extconf.rb failed ***

Comment: An error occurred while installing pg (0.17.1), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install pg -v '0.17.1'` succeeds before bundling.

Comment: just add this to your app and try to deploy to heroku. Don't execute bundle install. If you want to deploy on your machine, you need to install pg locally. Apparently you don't have it installed.

Comment: solved it. I had to install Xcode Tools, then I could install postgresql and the bundle install succeeded. Now my website is live on Heroku but the css styles are not yet active, but that's an other story. Thanks railsr for your help! Anthony